# Solving the exponent n without guessing or calculator

Tags: sequences-and-series

While this is a rather simple exercise, Im looking to understand fully the operations behind finding the exponent. I found tuts that use log in the calculator, and I just dont really understand that yet. Can anyone run me through the arithmatic or perhaps the topic I need to learn about to understand the subject fully?
Please check the photo for the exercise that I've solved by just mashing the multiplication button until I hit the result.
[Exercise 1. Sum of series.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSdEi.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Answer (score 0):

Factor out 4096 into primes. Which will be $2^{12}$. Then write it as $4^6$. And compare both sides.[image]

Comment: Can you pleaes add a photo or math jax?

Comment: Sure. Done. There is easier ways to find factors. But attaching a descriptive way.

Comment: I appreciate the contribution but I fail to understand why it works, why factoring out a prime number? Pretty creative way of thinking about it.. What about fractures? I have another exercise that has 2/3 as the q of the series, and I cannot get an answer.. what then ?